# playing a playlist created in windows

Tags: windows, music

I had created a playlist in windows 8 which was in .wpl format.
I later converted it to .m3u format. 
But i am not being able to play from either of the two on my ubuntu 14.04 which is on the same machine as my windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Here's how I did it I replaced this part of my Windows playlist:

```
C:\Users\username\Music\
```

with

```
/home/username/Music/
```

Then replaced the `\` with `/`, which got the playlist to play in VLC, but not Banshee.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!
The answer that you provided here could be improved by 1) Providing the details of how you made the edits to the playlists: What program did you use? Where in the file should one look to make the replacements?, etc. and 2) Use the formatting options. You can for example mark the relevant paths as `code`, thus making the post easier to read.
Again, welcome, and thank you for helping your peers!

Comment: Sorry, I don't hang out in forums. 

I used open office editor (but most text editors will work)  and used the find-replace command. I did global replace to make the changes. Save in original file format after editing. I find this method works in most players these days.

Answer (score 0):

use vlc. open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and then open the wpl or m3u with vlc player.

Comment: thank you but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late, but I'm posting this for other future visitors of this thread:

Apart from downloading VLC 
(which has created a bit of a headache for me trying to set the hotkeys only to find out that the hotkeys failed to work after the first time it was set, but that's another story.)
, you can use **Video**(the Ubuntu built-in movie player).

But note that you need to edit your playlist's text file in gedit/Vim before it can be played properly. Also, you need to make sure that your playlist is in the proper location before it can be played by Video.

Here's the detailed procedures:

1. Trasnfer the WHOLE music folder from Windows onto your Linux machine. (e.g. say the folder is initially E:\MyWindows\Music on the Windows machine, which includes a sub folder E:\MyWindows\Music\Instrumental)
2. Transfer your playlist also from Windows to Linux (if it is not already in the file transferred in the previous step), into the **same** destination file.
3. Open terminal in the destination directory (e.g. say you have put it in /home/MyUbuntu/Music, then open terminal and type
   `cd Music`)
4. Once you're in that directory, type `gedit [InsertPlaylistNameHere].wpl` (or use Vim if you )
5. `Ctrl + H` to delete all "E:\MyWindows\Music\" (i.e. the file location appending the song name) and replace all "E:\MyWindows\Music\Instrumental\" to "Instrumental/"

   Note the change in the direction of the last slash.

Once you're done just close the gedit and open the .wpl with Video. It should work, although the album arts may not show.

*(I have not found a method to make it work with Rhythmbox though.)*